# Variables not updating Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

The x and y within self.p dont update
Self.p is a draw variable

as you use the arrow keys they change the x and button the x doesn't change in the variable P
..................................................................................

```
self.P = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)

self.OB = pygame.Rect(self.oX, self.oY, self.width, self.height)
```

Sorry about formatting

here's my code:

```py
import pygame
import time
pygame.init()


pygame.display.set_caption('Platformer')
class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        self.DEBUG=True
        self.x=7
        self.y=400
        self.tX=1200
        self.tY=600
        self.width=40
        self.height=60
        self.vel=9
        self.run=True
        self.isJump=False
        self.jumpCount=10
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.clock.tick(60)
        self.flag = False
        self.win=pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 600))
        self.font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 64)
        self.dieText = self.font.render('Well crap', True, (255,0,0), (245,245,245))
        self.dieRect = self.dieText.get_rect()
        self.dieRect.center = (self.tX // 2, self.tY // 2)
        self.die = False
        self.dieFlag = False
        self.pause = False
        self.pauseFlag=False
        self.pauseText = self.font.render('Pause', True, (0,150,150), (245,245,245))
        self.pauseRect = self.pauseText.get_rect()
        self.pauseRect.center = (self.tX // 2, 150)
        self.oX = 400
        self.oY = 400
        self.P = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)
        self.OB = pygame.Rect(self.oX, self.oY, self.width, self.height)
        self.pColor = (0,0,0)
        self.oColor = (255, 0, 0)
    def GameLoop(self):
        while self.run:
            if self.DEBUG==True:
                print(self.x)
                print(self.P)
                print(self.OB)
                if self.flag == False:
                    print('yes')
                if self.pauseFlag==True:
                    print('ok')

            pygame.time.delay(15)

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()
                    self.run == False
            keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

            if self.die == True:
                self.dieFlag=True

            if self.pause == True:
                self.pauseFlag=True
            if self.pause==False:
                self.pauseFlag=False
            if keys[pygame.K_p]:
                self.pause=True
            if keys[pygame.K_o]:
                self.pause=False
            if keys[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            if self.die==False and self.pause==False:
                if self.flag == False and keys[pygame.K_SPACE] or keys[pygame.K_UP]:
                    self.starttime = pygame.time.get_ticks()
                    self.flag = True
                    self.isJump=True
                if self.flag == True and pygame.time.get_ticks() - self.starttime >= 475:
                    self.flag = False


                if keys[pygame.K_p] and self.pause==False and self.die == False:
                    self.pause=True
                if keys[pygame.K_o] and self.pause== True:
                    self.pause=False
                if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and self.x > self.vel:
                    self.x-=self.vel
                if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and self.x < 1200 - self.width - self.vel :
                    self.x+=self.vel
                if keys[pygame.K_k]:
                    self.die=True
                if not(self.isJump):
                    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and self.y < 600 - self.height - self.vel:
                        self.y += 0


                else:
                    if self.jumpCount >= -10:
                        self.y -= (self.jumpCount * abs(self.jumpCount)) * .55
                        self.jumpCount -= 1
                    else:
                        self.jumpCount = 10
                        self.isJump = False
            if self.dieFlag == True:
                self.win.fill((245,245,245))
                if self.pauseFlag == True:
                    self.win.blit(self.pauseText, self.pauseRect)
                    pygame.draw.rect(self.win, self.oColor, (self.oX,self.oY, 100, 200))
                    pygame.draw.rect(self.win, self.pColor, (self.x,self.y, self.width, self.height))
                    self.win.blit(self.dieText, self.dieRect)
                    pygame.display.update()
                elif self.pauseFlag==False:
                    pygame.draw.rect(self.win, self.oColor, (self.oX,self.oY, 100, 200))
                    pygame.draw.rect(self.win, self.pColor, (self.x,self.y, self.width, self.height))
                    self.win.blit(self.dieText, self.dieRect)
                    pygame.display.update()
            elif self.dieFlag == False:
                if self.pauseFlag == True:
                    self.win.fill((245,245,245))
                    self.win.blit(self.pauseText, self.pauseRect)
                    pygame.draw.rect(self.win, self.oColor, (self.oX,self.oY, 100, 200))
                    pygame.draw.rect(self.win, self.pColor, (self.x,self.y, self.width, self.height))
                    pygame.display.update()
                elif self.pauseFlag==False:
                    self.win.fill((245,245,245))
                    pygame.draw.rect(self.win, self.oColor, (self.oX,self.oY, 40, 60))
                    pygame.draw.rect(self.win, self.pColor, (self.x,self.y, self.width, self.height))
                    pygame.display.update()
g=Game()
g.GameLoop()
```

Any help very appreciated
Also sorry about formatting

Comment: What do you mean? *"The variables within these variables don't update"* is very unclear.

Comment: You should add your current output, as well as your expected output. Also, where do you call any code that supposedly updates those variables?

Comment: Are you expecting the `Rect`s to change when the variables whose *values* you used when creating them change? There is no connection between them - . (It is the same as how `x = 0; y = x; x = 1; print(y)` prints 0, not 1.)

Comment: Of course `self.P.x` doesn't magically change when `self.x` changes. When you do `self.P = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)` then the object  `self.P` is created and the value of `self.x` is copied to `self.P.x`. From this point on these are different value objects which are not connected. Initially they have the same integral value, but that's all.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not missing something, in the code you posted, there is no place where you acctually change the value of P and OB..?

Note, that these two variables are specific to the instance of your class. They are 'instance variables'

I would recommend
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-class-and-instance-variables-in-python-3
to understand the difference between class and instance variables.